# Run NestJS script from command line

Tags: typescript, command, nestjs

I want to be able to run a script that parses an XML file using NestJS framework for a proof-of-concept, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I created a `scripts` directory inside `/src` and placed my `script.ts` with an initial console.log there.  How can I run commands within that file? Should I change the script.ts file to plain javascript instead of typescript and then run node myscript.ts? What is the correct approach for this manner?

Comment: Found a more thorough answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250657/using-services-inside-nestjs-script-run-from-command-line/65522338#65522338

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to run my ts file using `npx ts-node my-file.ts`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `bin` property to your `package.json` with the name of the command you want to give, and the js file associated with the command. From there, if you were to run "commandName", you *should* get the command to properly run (after building from Typescript to JavaScript of course). As an example, you [can see this](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/master/package.json#L10). The original command file is written in Typescript, given a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) of `#!/usr/bin/env node` to allow for `node` to be used as the script runner, and then compiled into JavaScript with the rest of the library. From there, I just run `ogma <file_name>` and let the script take care of the rest.

For you, adding in Nest will be a step on top of this, but still pretty easy to manage as you'll have the entry file use the `NestFactory` to create the application and then pass the expected data into some sort of handler [as described briefly here](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications). Feel free to comment if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try standalone-applications

https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications

or nest-commander

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is `ts-node`. If you have a Typescript class that does the parsing of XML and does not directly depend on something within Nest you can use [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node). If your application requires you to be running Nest in order to do the parsing of XML you can start the server and make a command line request using CURL following a pattern similar to [this](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76)