# Using services inside NestJS script run from command line

Tags: typescript, command-line, nestjs

I know how to run a script from command line, using `npm` or `npx ts-node [script.ts]` just as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60704316/run-nestjs-script-from-command-line).

My question is different, now that I can run scripts, can I use services that are inside modules in my project? Let's say that I have this structure that it is normally called inside the project by other modules:

foo/foo.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  providers: [FooService],
  imports: [HttpModule],
  exports: [FooService]
})
export class FooModule { }
```

foo/foo.service.ts

```
import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
    constructor(
        private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    ) {}

    bar() {
        console.log('do stuff');
    }
}
```

how can I call `bar()` inside the file `/src/script.ts` and then call `npx ts-node script.ts` keeping all the imports? Thank you.

Comment: have you check this package ? [nestjs-command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-command)

Comment: @antoineso no, I'll give a try. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let say you have an application module like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

And an UserService used by UsersModule in this way:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

And you want to create a command to create a new user directly from command line.

You can create a file named `console.ts` and put the following content:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApplicationModule } from './application.module';
import { UsersService } from './users/users.service';

async function bootstrap() {
  const application = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(
    ApplicationModule,
  );

  const command = process.argv[2];

  switch (command) {
    case 'create-administrator-user':
      const usersService = application.get(UsersService);
      await usersService.create({
        username: 'administrator',
        password: 'password',
      });
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Command not found');
      process.exit(1);
  }

  await application.close();
  process.exit(0);
}

bootstrap();
```

And now in your `package.json` you can create the following script:

```
"execute": "ts-node ./src/console.ts"
```

Now you have the ability to call a custom command in a NestJS context like in the following example:

```
// Using Yarn
yarn execute create-administrator-user

// Using NPM
npm run execute create-administrator-user
```

Comment: So, the only thing is that I was forced to convert all the imports of my project from `src/[...]` to relative paths because it wasn't able to resolve them. For the rest it works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: Just a thing that came up in my mind, if I have some nest cron jobs in the project and it happens that in the moment that I run the script it is also in the time of a cron job, is it executed or not?

Comment: I am using prisma and cache in the services's `constructor` , it return `Cannot find module 'src/prisma.service'` error.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the @Emanuele answer. If you have issue with src/[...] relative path, then instead of running the script with ts-node, try run with the following
"node -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register path_to_script"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, to use a service you'll need to instantiate the service class. Nest normally does this as a part of `NestFactory.create`. What you could do is something like this:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(FooModule);
  const service = app.get<FooService>(FooService); // this sets the type of service and gets the instance
  service.bar();
  await app.close();
}
```

Now all you would need is to compile the files and run them using `node` as you normally would a server.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the relative path issue, add this to the ts-config

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

Source: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/paths/